# When can I use Bastion of Mental Clarity?

Tags: dnd-4e

If I use Bastion of Mental Clarity as an immediate interrupt, does it pump my will for the attack that just happened or is it in effect afterwards?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**It works in time to bump your Will.**

As immediate interrupt, the effects of [Bastion of Mental Clarity](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/power.aspx?id=7548)<sup>DDI</sup> take place before the event described in its trigger occurs.
This is a prerogative of immediate interrupts, and it's fairly common to see defensive powers working that way.

Beware that creatures are limited to 1 immediate action (either interrupt or reaction) per round of combat.